# i get this error when i tried to lunch my firt project with spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot initializer example with mySQL .

When I launch my application, I am getting the error below.

Any pointers for this issue?

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

i tried to run this !!!!

```
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc://localhost:3306/tp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

Comment: `jdbc://localhost:3306/tp` is an invalid JDBC url. For mysql it should be something like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tp`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

or another Dialect version for you project

Answer (score 0):

To develop spring/boot application with Mysql then follow below step

```
Remove H2 Dependency From pom.xml 
<!--
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
-->


Add a Dependency for MYSQL Database Connector to pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> Setup Your MySQL Database in your local system or any remote location.

```
Configure application.properties to connect to your database.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<DBNAME>
spring.datasource.username=<USERNAME>
spring.datasource.password=<PASSWORD>
```

Follow the step and let us know for any issue